# Excel VBA Submit Button Debug

Tags: excel

I'm new in Excel VBA. I want to make automatic journal entry with excel. But i have some trouble in my Submit Button. Here's my code :

```
Sub Submit_Data()

Dim database As Worksheet
Dim form As Worksheet

Set database = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
Set form = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")

'''''''''' Validations ''''''''''''''
If form.Range("H2").Value = True Then
    MsgBox "Please Enter Date of This Transaction", vbCritical, "Data Entry Form"
    Exit Sub
End If

If form.Range("H4").Value = True Then
    MsgBox "Please Enter Description of This Transaction", vbCritical, "Data Entry Form"
    Exit Sub
End If

If form.Range("H6").Value = True Then
    MsgBox "Please Choose This Type of Journal", vbCritical, "Data Entry Form"
    Exit Sub
End If

If form.Range("L10").Value <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Sum of Debet and Sum of Credit is not Balance", vbCritical, "Data Entry Form"
    Exit Sub
End If

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim Last_Row As Long
Dim Input_Data As ListObject
Dim Input_Date As Range
Dim Input_Journal_Code As Range
Dim Input_Type As Range
Dim Input_Acc_Code As Range
Dim Input_Acc_Name As Range
Dim Input_Description As Range
Dim Input_Detail As Range
Dim Input_Amount As Range
Dim Input_Position As Range

Last_Row = database.Range("D1").Value + 3

Set Input_Data = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Input_Data")
Set Input_Date = Input_Data.ListColumns("Date").DataBodyRange
Set Input_Journal_Code = Input_Data.ListColumns("Journal Code").DataBodyRange
Set Input_Type = Input_Data.ListColumns("Type").DataBodyRange
Set Input_Acc_Code = Input_Data.ListColumns("Account Code").DataBodyRange
Set Input_Acc_Name = Input_Data.ListColumns("Account Name").DataBodyRange
Set Input_Description = Input_Data.ListColumns("Description").DataBodyRange
Set Input_Detail = Input_Data.ListColumns("Detail").DataBodyRange
Set Input_Amount = Input_Data.ListColumns("Amount").DataBodyRange
Set Input_Position = Input_Data.ListColumns("Position").DataBodyRange

'''''''''''' Update Values in Database

database.Range("A" & Last_Row).Value = form.Range(Input_Date).Value
database.Range("B" & Last_Row).Value = form.Range(Input_Journal_Code).Value
database.Range("C" & Last_Row).Value = form.Range(Input_Type).Value
database.Range("D" & Last_Row).Value = form.Range(Input_Acc_Code).Value
database.Range("E" & Last_Row).Value = form.Range(Input_Acc_Name).Value
database.Range("F" & Last_Row).Value = form.Range(Input_Description).Value
database.Range("G" & Last_Row).Value = form.Range(Input_Detail).Value
database.Range("H" & Last_Row).Value = form.Range(Input_Amount).Value
database.Range("I" & Last_Row).Value = form.Range(Input_Position).Value

''''' Clear the data
form.Range(Input_Acc_Code).ClearContents
form.Range(Input_Detail).ClearContents
form.Range(Input_Amount).ClearContents
form.Range(Input_Position).ClearContents
form.Range("H2:H6").ClearContents


MsgBox "Data has been Submitted Successfully", vbInformation, "Data Entry Form"

End Sub
```

When i click Submit button, it showed Debug on "Update Database" and "Clear Data". Is there any advise to solve my problem. the message box show : Run-time Error 1004 Method 'Range' of object '_worksheet' failed. Thank you

Comment: Could you please check if sheets "Database" and "Input" exists on the workbook when macro runs?

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to achieve with `database.Range("A" & Last_Row).Value = form.Range(Input_Date).Value`, in particular `form.Range(Input_Date).Value`?  (`Input_Date` is a range object, which you have alreadey set. Using it in this way makes no sence).

Comment: Are you using the listobject on the database-sheet or on the forms-sheet? It would make more sense to have the "database" as a listobject - but from your code it doesn't look like this